# Is it now necessary to adapt UI to fit iOS 6?

Tags: ios

Is it now necessary to fit iOS 6(My first question)?
At present, the latest iOS OS version has arrived iOS9. However, I wonder if it is necessary to take iOS 6 into consideration when we are developing application. We always desire to cut down effort on developing, but we either don`t wanna lose users who are using iOS6.

Comment: It is up to you.  Apple doesn't require you to support anything earlier than iOS 9

Comment: No you don't need to support iOS 6. In fact you can also kill iOS 7 support. 92 % of all iPhone are running on iOS 8 or higher.

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do so, and it sounds like you don't, then do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends slightly on your target market, but my first answer would definitely be no.

You would be seriously limiting yourself, less from a design perspective, but from the point of view of code. Each iOS version adds (and removes) quite a bit to the SDKs. As a developer it would be a lot more work to support iOS6.

Taking into account the statistics available, for example from apple (https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) - any new apps I am developing from the new year will support only iOS9 and existing apps have already dropped support for iOS7.

Also worth noting, every device, back to the iPhone 4S, released in 2011, supports iOS9.

Comment: I am fond of your opinion "You would be seriously limiting yourself, less from a design perspective, but from the point of view of code". That is right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could develop an iOS 6-compatible application. And I love iOS 6 with all my heart. However, it takes a lot of work to make an app iOS 6-compatible. You can't use certain APIs (a lot) which appeared in iOS 7, 8, 9. Also, you should consider, that UI elements look different on iOS 6, so you'll have to make two different versions of design.
According to [this unofficial statistics](https://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) (which is rather popular among iOS developers AFAIK), iOS is installed on about 2.1% of devices (and I envy people who have those devices, to be honest).

The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Think how many customers you will lose if you don't run on iOS 6. All these people with an iPhone 3GS will come and haunt you. But seriously, these people are not buying apps for their old phones anymore. There is no need to support iOS 6 at all.

In practice, very few people are using iOS 7 today, and the only ones who *must* use it are those with an iPhone 4. The iPhone 4 is also substantially slower than any later phone, so you would have to be very careful doing anything that is CPU intensive. I have code that runs *immediately* on an iPhone 6, a bit slowly on a 4s, and with long waiting times on an iPhone 4.

And in practice, Xcode 7 doesn't support building for iOS 7 anymore. So you stay with Xcode 6.4 (and Swift 1.2, and an older version of Objective-C) if you want to support iOS 7, or with some really old version of Xcode if you want to support iOS 6. And nobody here will be able to help you with any problems.

And in practice, there was a huge design change between iOS 6 and iOS 7. You need twice the design effort, or your app will look like crap on one of them.